# How to fix hang issue due to background thread in outlook Add-In

Tags: c++, multithreading, outlook-addin

I am writing a Add-In (plug-In) for Outlook. I need a thread in my plug-In to keep running for life time of outlook to handle various events and to perform network operations asynchronously.

I have written a background thread for this purpose which have infinite loop to keep this thread alive. It is working good in normal situation. But In following circumstances it is the making outlook un-responsive:--

Step 1- Leave the outlook running.
Step 2- Lock the windows system
Step 3- Unlock it after 1 minute.

When I disable my plug-in from outlook, it works good in same sue cases. I have implemented background thread in following manner :--

```
void BackgroundTaskManager::onDoWork(System::Object^ sender, 
 DoWorkEventArgs^ e)
{
 try
 {
    while (e->Cancel == false)
    {
        mRemoveList->Clear();
        for each(KeyValuePair<uint64_t, BackgroundTask^>^ task in 
          mTasks)
        {
            task->Value->checkStarted();

            if (task->Value->isComplete)
            {
                mRemoveList->Add(task->Key);
            }
        }

        for each(uint64_t taskID in mRemoveList)
        {
            mTasks->Remove(taskID);
            DarkEventLog::Debug(String::Format("Completed task 
            removed. {0}", taskID));
        }
        Sleep(1000);
        if (DarkClientManager::instance->isRunning == false)
            break;
     }
  }
  catch (System::Exception^ ex)
  {
    throw ex;
  }
}
```

In above code even if mtasks and mRemovelists are empty, still I could see from prints that Outlook is unresponsive and this thread is running. Can somebody please help me what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Have you tried to pause Outlook when running under the debugger?

Comment: I was not able to reproduce in debug but on production, we could reproduce even if I create simple thread with having event loop in it. Event loop in this thread is ensuring that this thread would be alive for whole life of outlook. Is there any limitation in outlook plug-in ? Like we can not implement a thread in plug-in with keep alive feature ?

Comment: One more finding is that my event loop is keep printing even when outlook has hanged. That means there is no deadlock.

Comment: On further analysis, we have found that we are facing this issue while using our plug-in with cisco webex and citrix plug-in. So it could be combination of 3 plug-ins, which is causing us hang issue. Because of that, I have following doubts in my mind :---

1- Is there any way to define the order of loading of plug-in ? In registry settings (HKCU / software / Microsoft / Office / AddIns) plugins are available in alphabetical order. Does it has any relation with order of loading of plug-ins.

Comment: 2- Did Microsoft outlook ensures ordering in firing of events also (theoretically or practically) ? Is there any way we could define that if 2 plug-ins are registered for same event (lets say send event), then who will get first for send event ?

3- Does outlook ensures thread safety for event handlers ?- that means if a send event is handled by one one plug-In then, it will not raise event for other plug-in until first plug-in will finish their job.

Comment: 4- Does outlook ensure atomicity of mail object if above condition (3rd point) is not satisfied. That means if 2 plug-in are handling the send event, and thats why working on same mail object, they will not end up in modifying same copy. Either it will have first plug-in's modification or second one's modification ?

Comment: What event? Which event exactly are you processing? Please show that code.